# Error in trigger

Tags: mysql

Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with this trigger? I have spend 1 hour trying to solve it but unfortunately no success, thank you.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  `pt_hotels_zero_check`BEFORE INSERT ON pt_hotels
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(pt_hotels.touroperator_of = 0) THEN
    SIGNAL '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '0 value not allowed';
END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

i get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '0 value not allowed';
END IF;
```

END' at line 5

Comment: what is SIGNAL used for ?

Comment: i have read is needed to generate the message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax for the SIGNAL statement is:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '0 value not allowed';
```

See the doc at:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: Alf this i got now:
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER  `pt_hotels_zero_check`BEFORE INSERT ON     pt_hotels
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(pt_hotels.touroperator_of = 0) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '0 value not allowed';
END IF; 
END$$
DELIMITER;

and i get this erro:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 9

Comment: If you define the delimiter as 'DELIMITER //', use 'END //' then, not 'END $$'

Comment: i had already tried that but got the same error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '//;
DELIMITER' at line 8

Comment: the code is ok now i guess but i get this message now:
 This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: @papacico Looks like you already defined this trigger, use DROP TRIGGER before creating it again to replace the trigger. Also, don't forget to accept this answer.